# When i put a <div> into my html i get a huge space between text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a  on the left side of the screen. I can get the div to show up and work, but It does not allow any text to  be next to it. please any help or tips would be great thanks. The  I am having trouble with is "bannerL"

here is my html:

```
         <html>
     <head>
<title>Paid To Click</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>


   <div id="bannerL">
   <a href="">
 <img src=""></a>
   </div>

<div id="ebook">
<a href="">
<img src="">
</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

here is my css:

```
body    {
      background-image: url("beach.gif");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-attachment: fixed;
      background-position: center;
 }

 p { color:#000000;line-height:2em;}

 p.margin{
     margin-top: 0px;
     margin-bottom: 0px;
       margin-right: 250px;
        margin-left: 250px;
  }

  #banner {position:relative; margin:auto auto;}

 #header{background-color: #fff; width: 1000px; position: relative; }

  #bannerL {position: relative;
float:left;
}

   #bannerR {
     position: relative; 
     float: right; 
  }

  #ebook {position: relative; margin: auto auto;}
```

Comment: Please keep your code examples short and relevant. This is WAY to much to comprehend when not being familiar with the code. Try to reproduce your problem is as little HTML/CSS required; post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) link to a testcase.

Comment: thanks, im new. ill go back and edit as much out as i can.

Comment: Also leave out crap like referral links, affiliate programs etc. and remove the link to your site. A JSFiddle (again, without the referral/affiliate links) will do just fine.

Comment: okay, my apologies. what is a JSfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LThXw/    Thanks for all the guidance. im really new to this.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LThXw/1/ I just updated it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are doing your margins pretty wrong. If you want those paragraphs centered use text-align: center. This margin-left and margin-right: 250px is why your text (if it is in paragraphs) is being pushed away from anything else. But still, if that isn't your problem a negative margin will always fix your problem. You set your "text", whatever that is, to have margin-left: -100px (for example). One more thing - it is better to have only one element (the wrapped div) with a value fixed in pixels, and the others in %, so they resize according to this value. Then you can make the page resize according to one's resolution with media querys. But for now I suggest simply using this, as your whole page is messed up. Later you can think about making it look nice on all resolutions

```
margin-left: -100px;
```

Comment: I changed text "margin-left: -100px;" and i still have the gap, do you know any good palces to learn so i don't have to ask so many questions? I tried W3, html.net, codeacedmy.org. But i guess i still am learning it wrong.

Comment: just post your code only of the 2 elements you have trouble alligning. The websites you are using are good, but you can't learn anything without loads of writing and having someone to fix your mistakes. I have been learning since this autumn, but I have no problems with html and css already, as I have good teachers to help me out...

Comment: You can use this site to share your code and everybody cann see how it works...http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/W4SaZ/1/    

I think this is what you are asking for. let me know if it is not

Comment: I edited the Jfiddle. ALso when I put the Margin-left:-110px on it makes my text go off the screen to the left. any tips?